# How to update a field inside the array of object of another array of objects in mongo db? or How to update a field using the array index in mongo db?

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, database, mongodb

This is the structure of my collection of mongodb database. I need to update the status inside each order products. What I need to do?

```
{
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "633ab3c11e6e97b6332f56a1"
  },
  "orders": [
    {
      "date": "6/10/2022",
      "productDetails": {
        "0": {
          "name": "Top",
          "price": "1235",
          "quantity": 1,
          "status": "placed"
        },
        "1": {
          "name": "Shirt",
          "price": "1235",
          "quantity": 1,
          "status": "placed"
        }
      },
      "billingAddress": {
        "address": "My Address",
        "city": "City",
        "state": "State",
        "country": "Country",
        "pincode": "123456",
        "contact": "1234567890"
      },
      "paymentMode": "cod"
    },
    {
      "date": "6/10/2022",
      "productDetails": {
        "0": {
          "name": "Top",
          "price": "1235",
          "quantity": 3,
          "status": "placed"
        },
        "1": {
          "name": "Shirt",
          "price": "1235",
          "quantity": 1,
          "status": "placed"
        }
      },
      "billingAddress": {
        "address": "My Address",
        "city": "City",
        "state": "State",
        "country": "Country",
        "pincode": "123456",
        "contact": "1234567890"
      },
      "paymentMode": "cod"
    },
    {
      "date": "6/10/2022",
      "productDetails": {
        "0": {
          "name": "Shirt",
          "price": "234",
          "quantity": 1,
          "status": "placed"
        },
        "1": {
          "name": "Top",
          "price": "123",
          "quantity": 1,
          "status": "placed"
        }
      },
      "billingAddress": {
        "address": "My Address",
        "city": "City",
        "state": "State",
        "country": "Country",
        "pincode": "123456",
        "contact": "1234567890"
      },
      "paymentMode": "cod"
    }
  ]
}
```

I want to update the order product status to shipped, canceled, etc. I have to set status in desired position like the following.
I waant to update the mongodb databse and have to get the result in like the following result.

```
{
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "633ab3c11e6e97b6332f56a1"
  },
  "orders": [
    {
      "date": "6/10/2022",
      "productDetails": {
        "0": {
          "name": "Top",
          "price": "1235",
          "quantity": 1,
          "status": "caneled"
        },
        "1": {
          "name": "Shirt",
          "price": "1235",
          "quantity": 1,
          "status": "shipped"
        }
      },
      "billingAddress": {
        "address": "My Address",
        "city": "City",
        "state": "State",
        "country": "Country",
        "pincode": "123456",
        "contact": "1234567890"
      },
      "paymentMode": "cod"
    },
    {
      "date": "6/10/2022",
      "productDetails": {
        "0": {
          "name": "Top",
          "price": "1235",
          "quantity": 3,
          "status": "canceled"
        },
        "1": {
          "name": "Shirt",
          "price": "1235",
          "quantity": 1,
          "status": "shipped"
        }
      },
      "billingAddress": {
        "address": "My Address",
        "city": "City",
        "state": "State",
        "country": "Country",
        "pincode": "123456",
        "contact": "1234567890"
      },
      "paymentMode": "cod"
    },
    {
      "date": "6/10/2022",
      "productDetails": {
        "0": {
          "name": "Shirt",
          "price": "234",
          "quantity": 1,
          "status": "placed"
        },
        "1": {
          "name": "Top",
          "price": "123",
          "quantity": 1,
          "status": "shipped"
        }
      },
      "billingAddress": {
        "address": "My Address",
        "city": "City",
        "state": "State",
        "country": "Country",
        "pincode": "123456",
        "contact": "1234567890"
      },
      "paymentMode": "cod"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Create an post api to update the status by passing respective order's ID.

Comment: ```db.collection.find({
  _id: ObjectId("633ab3c11e6e97b6332f56a1")
},
{
  $set: {
    "orders.$[element].productDetails.$[element].status": false
  }
},
{ arrayFilters: [ { element: 0 } ]}
)```

Comment: Is this correct or not?

Comment: Wrong. With `find()` method you can only get the documents. Use `findByIdAndUpdate()` method.

Comment: According to my research, the correct method is as follows:```db.orders.update({_id: ObjectId("633a6a73dd9f8cce0029e53d")},{$set:{"orders.0.productDetails.0.status": "shipped"}})```

Answer (score 1):

According to my research, the correct method is as follows:

```
db.orders.updateOne({_id: ObjectId("633a6a73dd9f8cce0029e53d")},{$set:{"orders.0.productDetails.0.status": "shipped"}})
```

And the result is :-

```
{
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "633ab3c11e6e97b6332f56a1"
  },
  "orders": [
    {
      "_id": {
        "$oid": "633e8f2d3e3f12f07438cc64"
      },
      "date": "6/10/2022",
      "productDetails": {
        "0": {
          "name": "Top",
          "price": "1235",
          "quantity": 1,
          "status": "shipped"
        },
        "1": {
          "name": "Shirt",
          "price": "1235",
          "quantity": 1,
          "status": "placed"
        }
      },
      "billingAddress": {
        "address": "My Address",
        "city": "City",
        "state": "State",
        "country": "Country",
        "pincode": "123456",
        "contact": "1234567890"
      },
      "paymentMode": "cod"
    },
    {
      "_id": {
        "$oid": "633e96533e3f12f07438cc65"
      },
      "date": "6/10/2022",
      "productDetails": {
        "0": {
          "name": "Top",
          "price": "1235",
          "quantity": 1,
          "status": "placed"
        },
        "1": {
          "name": "Shirt",
          "price": "1235",
          "quantity": 1,
          "status": "placed"
        },
        "2": {
          "name": "Jeans",
          "price": "1234",
          "quantity": 1,
          "status": "placed"
        }
      },
      "billingAddress": {
        "address": "My Address",
        "city": "City",
        "state": "State",
        "country": "Country",
        "pincode": "123456",
        "contact": "1234567890"
      },
      "paymentMode": "cod"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: FYI, `update()` method is deprecated. You may have researched the old docs. Follow the latest docs.

Comment: To update, I will use `updateOne()` . Thank you for your information